# Can we disconnect an object from the pull of gravity using some material?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, classical-mechanics, gravity

I have once come across a material/ substance/ compound,  or something, that cuts off objects from Earth's gravitational pull.

In other words, it would keep the object suspended in the air and will not allow it to touch the ground, hence, we can say that this is a barrier between the object and the earth's gravity.

Can you please give me the name and properties of this material / substance / compound / gas / or what ever it is?

Comment: No such material exists.

Comment: *"I have once come across a materiel / substance / compound / or something that keeps objects cut off from the earth's gravitational pull."*...you almost surely haven't.

Comment: The material/substance/compound you came across most likely has the properties of a hallucinogen.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri This is one of the greatest SE comments that I have ever seen.

Comment: This question can not be answered as it requests the name of a material that does not exist.

Comment: Come on guys. When somebody has no idea of what is going on and asks an honest question about it, how does mocking him help?

Answer (score 3):

As Jimmy360 said, no such a material exists. You must have been experiencing something else, such as levitation by magnets, flux pinning/quantum locking/quantum trapping, or some other principle that made you think you saw a material that made a barrier with gravity. I am not sure where you saw this "gravity barrier" material, but it could have been a magic trick played by somebody(even somebody that isn't a magician) where there may have been a hidden string or other object.